# How do you truncate or round numbers by units NOT decimals?

Tags: mongodb

I have dates and times in number format of YYYYMMDDHHMMSS. As a group by for a sum, I want to have the ability to group by:

YYYYMM

YYYYMMDD

YYYYMMDDHH

I have previously used this below, but it converts it into a string, which isn't great:

```
"sum_by_date":  { $substrBytes: [ "$_id.transaction_date", 0, 7
```

] }

What I want to achieve from 20181217134218 for by month is either:

201812 or 20181200000000 and kept as a number format.

Thanks, Matt

Comment: What is your mongo version?

Comment: version 4.0 - I was able to resolve this as below using "sum_by_date": {$trunc:{$divide: ["$_id.transaction_date", 100000000 ]}}. Thanks

Comment: You can use `$toDate` aggregation to convert it into date and then `$month` to get the `$group` by result

Comment: thanks for that, I'll give that a go as alternative method, much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use integer division to truncate the number. In Ruby:

```
(20181217134218 / 100000000) * 100000000  # = 20181200000000
```

Comment: thanks for this, I'll have to work through in MongoScript but that is excellent, I thought there might be a formula for that :)

Comment: ah, tried this:
"sum_by_date":  { $multiply : [{ $divide: [ "$_id.transaction_date", 100000000 ]}, 100000000 ]}
but it came back to same value

Comment: Thanks for the help with this, I ended up using a variation on this and it has worked: "sum_by_date":  {$trunc:{$divide: ["$_id.transaction_date", 100000000 ]}}